# Are gene mutations patentable for diagnostics as in LQTS

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [US20150307941](https://www.google.com/patents/US20150307941)

Answer (score 2):

The document you cited is an application. It has since been granted as [US8658358](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8658358B1/en). So, the answer seems to be yes it is patentable since the USPTO granted a patent. Its important to note that the claims can change significantly from application to granted patent so you must read the claims of the granted patent to understand exactly what is being protected by the patent.